# Update the copyright information accross the project files

Tags: visual-studio, copyright-display

Please let me know if we can replace or update the copyright information accross all the project file automatically.

Is there any tool or script/cmd for doing this.( prefer Visual studio )

Comment: _which_ copyright information?

Comment: copyright information present in each header and c file . I want to change the year.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Find and Replace in Files dialog and switch the regular expression checkbox on. You can then use `:z` to match integers, so the following will replace all instances in the solution:

[image: Replace in files example]

Answer (score 0):

It's just plain text, from the comments, so a Search & Replace should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I have different copyright years in different files.e.g. : Copyright 20XX, company name , 20XX-20XX

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a tool to insert the copyright header in all the files of the project

http://www.amazify.com/licenseheader

People can use this tool for C & C++ files too.